# Changing the Navbar when user Logged in

Tags: reactjs, express, react-redux, mern, jwt

I am building a web app for my assignment and I am new to react. I simply want to change my navbar when I am logged in.

For example:

Before login:
[image]
after login:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a state which will store if the user logged in or not.
- Use That State to render components conditionally.

Sapmle app:

[image]

small example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ssdzi1?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Welcome and happy coding.